# Sencha Touch 2.2 List not reusing list-items

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a list linked to a store filled with Facebook friends. It contains around 350 records.
There is a searchfield at the top of the list which triggers the following function on keyup:

```
  filterList: function (value) {
    // console.time(value);
    if (value === null) return;

    var searchRegExp = new RegExp(value, 'g' + 'i'),
        all = Ext.getStore('Friends'),
        recent = Ext.getStore('Recent'),
        myFilter;

    all.clearFilter();
    recent.clearFilter();

    // console.log(value, searchRegExp);

    myFilter = function (record) {
      return searchRegExp.test(record.get('name'));
    }

    all.filter(myFilter);
    recent.filter(myFilter);
    // console.timeEnd(value);
  },
```

Now, this used to work fine with ST2.1.1 but since I upgraded the app to ST2.2. It's really slow. It even makes Safari freeze and crash on iOS...

This is what the logs give :

```
t /t/gi Friends.js:147
t: 457ms Friends.js:155
ti /ti/gi Friends.js:147
ti: 6329ms Friends.js:155
tit /tit/gi Friends.js:147
tit: 7389ms Friends.js:155
tito /tito/gi Friends.js:147
tito: 7137ms
```

Does anyone know why it behaves like this now, or does anyone have a better filter method.

**Update**

Calling `clearFilter` with a `true` paramater seems to speed up things, but it's not as fast as before yet.

**Update**

It actually has nothing to do with filtering the store.

It has to do with rendering list-items. Sencha apparently create a list-item for every record I have in the store instead of just creating a couple of list-items and reusing them

[image]

**Could there be an obvious reason it's behaving this way ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have the "infinite" config on your list set to true?

- http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-cfg-infinite

You probably don't want the list rendering 300+ rows at once, so setting that flag will reduce the amount of DOM that gets generated.

Comment: Thank you. "Default to false..." I just can't believe this. Such an important change (almost) without notice...